# Embedded HEX files in PHP

Tags: php, perl, cgi

Is it possible to write a virtual HEX file into a PHP page, and later generate the real file on the fly when the user requests the php page?

For example in Perl I use `__DATA__` followed by some HEX content

Comment: You can sure use [heredocs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for roughly the same task. But they produce strings, not virtual files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just dump your file to HEX form, assign it to variable and just go thru content of the variable and restore "real" bytes and send it out to the client. Or, if possible, use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). But this would be extremely ineffective for files larger than say 50KB.